# how to make stand-alone setup file of a mfc project including all data files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a project in VC++ MFC and works fine with the .mdb files. But just copying the project's  .exe file on other system does not let the project work as it searches for the same path as mentioned in the code for the .mdb files and fails to find one. Also, apart from .mdb files, theres a need for certain .ocx files and io library suite to be registered in the system prior to the project's execution. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap up all the files into a package also known as installer. One of the most popular (and free) at the moment is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). This will produce a single exe file that you will be deploying to users / other machines. You need to make sure that you include all the needed files, libraries etc in your setup.

Comment: i have tried using microsoft installsheild. even after including the files, what path do i provide in the code for the .mdb file. say it is now in "e:\\project\\try1.mdb". Unless i change the code to something it will look for the file in a similar path and respond with error. Additionally files like .ocx have to be registered manually in the system. so just wrapping up a package with the file did not help. user has to install all other libraries and register the .ocx files in order to proceed.

Comment: Regarding the mdb path, you probably need to use the relative path which is something you need to work out in your software. As for the dependent libraries you can also install those using the installer.

Comment: Certainly use **InnoSetup**.